# Make rule on drolls to check subdata

Tags: drools, jbpm

I have a package. Package includes a list of items. Item has a list of fields. I need to check if specific fields are set to correct value for all items in a package:

```
rule "Slapper"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        itm : item( ) from pkg.items
        List( size() == itm.size() ) from collect (
            field( fieldId == "111" , value == "1" ) from itm.fields
            field( fieldId == "222" , value == "2" ) from itm.fields
        ) from itm
    then
        ...
end
```

how I can get collection filtered by subfields?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use **accumulate** function:

```
List( size == pkg.items.size() ) from accumulate (
    $a: itemData( $field1: fields,  $field2: fields ) from pkg.items
    and
    fieldData( fieldId == "111" , value == "1" ) from $field1
    and
    fieldData( fieldId == "222" , value == "2" ) from $field2;
    collectList( $a )
)
```